# Doctrine inheritance in multiple namespace

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm currently working with Symfony2 and Doctrine2 to build a website which has several bundles of my own. Those I'm having trouble with are CoreBundle and UserBundle.

I want to make a Log manager to store several actions in DB. So, I made an abstract entity `Log` in the `CoreBundle` with the attributes I needed, and made the mapping with doctrine. No problem there.

Now, I would like to extend this class in the `UserBundle` for each type of `Log` that I want to store. I did that, added the `@InheritanceType` to the `Log` class, as well as the `@DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscrimiatorMap`. The entities being in another bundle, I fully named them in the map.

The problem is that when I try to it, Doctrine throws me an exception :
`Entity class 'EP\UserBunble\Entity\Log\LoginUserLog' used in the discriminator map of class 'EP\CoreBundle\Entity\Log\Log' does not exist.`

I don't get it because I already did something like this twice. The only difference was that all entities where in the same folder/namespace.

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Here are the source files :

1 - Log

```
namespace EP\CoreBundle\Entity\Log;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Log
 * @ORM\Table(name="ep_logs")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user_registration"="EP\UserBundle\Entity\Log\RegistrationUserLog", "user_login"="EP\UserBunble\Entity\Log\LoginUserLog"})
 */
abstract class Log{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="domain", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $domain;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(name="details", type="array")
     */
    protected $details;
}
```

2 - BaseUserLog :

```
namespace EP\UserBundle\Entity\Log;

use EP\DBAL\Types\EnumLogDomainType as LogDomain;
use EP\CoreBundle\Entity\Log\Log;
use EP\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * BaseUserLog
 */
abstract class BaseUserLog extends Log{
    const DEFAULT_DOMAIN = LogDomain::DOMAIN_USERS;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

3 - LoginUserLog

```
namespace EP\UserBundle\Entity\Log;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use EP\DBAL\Types\EnumLogActionType as LogAction;
use EP\UserBundle\Entity\Log\BaseUserLog;

/**
 * LoginUserLog
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class LoginUserLog extends BaseUserLog{
    const DEFAULT_ACTION = LogAction::ACTION_USER_LOGIN;

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L2606-L2608 -- do a little debugging around these lines.

Comment: Is your Doctrine mapping strategy is "auto_mapping" ? (defined in config.yml)

Comment: @bagonyi : I'm gonna take ae a look.

Comment: Spot the typo? EP\UserBunble\Entity

Comment: Really?  Bunble does not seem unusual to you?

Comment: did you get to the botttom of this. I have the same problem with inheritance